# What does mean by 9/5 in Next badge section?

Tags: support, badges

I noticed the following in my user activity -

[image]

What does the 9/5 mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means (as CarLaTeX already wrote) that you asked a well-received question on 9 separate days, although only 5 are required to earn this badge.

However you need to get a positive question record for this badge to be awarded to you.